# viewDidLoad is not being called while pushing a viewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, viewdidload

Here am trying to navigate to another viewController by clicking on a button.

It is navigating to next viewController, but `viewDidLoad()` is not calling here

Here is the code which i wrote to navigate to another viewController on clicking on a button

```
@IBAction func nextButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let OrdersVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(OrdersVC, animated: true)
}
```

and here is my viewController (which i need to navigate)

```
@IBOutlet weak var activeButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var upcomingButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Here am able to get into the class, but `viewDidLoad()` itself it is not calling.

How should i achieve this ?

[![Here is my storyboard][1]][1]

[image: Here is my storyboard with identity inspector]

Comment: So you telling us that you have at least 2 viewControllers in storyboard, first one is root in navigation controller, you calling push 2 vc and did not get viewDidload? Are you seeing transition at least?

Comment: Can you explain how are you constructing view controllers ? post your storyboard screenshot?

Comment: @tereks, yes i am using using more than 2 viewControllers. and first viewController is root view controller. And i embedded that 1st view controller to Navigation Controller. Yes i can see transition. the references which i took in viewController 2 is calling. But inside viewdidload() it is not getting

Comment: @SuganyaMarlin. i used viewWillAppear() also. It is also not being called

Comment: Actually viewDidLoad() will be called. Show ur storyboard

Comment: Did u set ur segue and use self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil) ?

Comment: @ammateja try this : let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: “StoryBoardName”, bundle:nil)
let nextViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourViewController")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)

Comment: i edited my question. storyboard added. @SuganyaMarlin & Mohammed

Comment: The only reason you getting this is that you did not connect storyboard vc with actual class itself in identity inspector

Comment: Actually, if you're doing it right, `viewDidLoad` will be called; It is not even an option, which means that there is probably something wrong of what you did so far.

Comment: no need to perform segue to work it should work

Comment: @ammateja show your "YourViewController" identity inspector

Comment: i edited my question. i added an image of my storyboard with identity inspector

Comment: what do you mean that "`Here am able to get into the class`" what does that mean?

Comment: @SuganyaMarlin, i want to do this process without any segues and my storyboard is added with identity inspector

Comment: @MilanNosáľ, the references which i took in viewController 2 is calling. but inside viewdidLoad() it is not getting

Comment: what is viewController 2? what references you took? how do you know it does not execute viewDidLoad?

Comment: viewController 2 means, loginViewController. i kept break point in viewDidLoad(). it didn't come inside viewDidLoad()

Comment: try to make the second lineof the nextButtonClicked to `self.navigationController!.pushViewController(OrdersVC, animated: true)`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the class is not settled in IB for that VC; make sure class you load and storyboard ID matches the one you want to load. For example, to load:

```
  let OrdersVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “secondID") as! secondViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(OrdersVC, animated: true)
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: i gave correct identifier only. see my edited question. there you can find my storyboard screenshot with identity inspector

Comment: can u send a demo of this problem

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to my mind when looking at your question:

1. Check that the `nextButtonClicked` method is connected to the button (the code there looks OK, so maybe it is just not executed).
2. Check if the `viewDidLoad` that you are speaking about is really in `LoginViewController` that you instantiate (and I hope you are testing the fact that `viewDidLoad` is called by setting a breakpoint on `super.viewDidLoad()`).

Comment: nextButtonClicked is connected. and after tapping on the button it is coming inside that button action also.

Answer (score 1):

Just write folloiwng line in between your push code

```
@IBAction func nextButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let OrdersVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController

_ = OrdersVC.view // write this line

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(OrdersVC, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: wrote that line, now viewDidLoad is calling. But it is not at all navigating to next viewController. it remains in 1st viewController only

Answer (score 0):

It often happens when the identifier with which you instantiate your ViewController from the storyboard is incorrect. For e.g.

`[[self getStoryboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:MyVC];`

If `MyVC` is the identifier of some other ViewController, this might happen.